How to align div in background-image
I'm trying to setup a modal popup that uses a background-image with a list within it. I want the modal list items to align with a box within the image itself, which I can easily do using margins/padding etc, however when I adjust the screen dimensions, the list items don't scale well with the image.
I've tried using different spacings/margins/units/grid/flex etc but nothing I could think of/find online seemed to do the trick.
The desired result would be having the list items adjust their heigh/width/front-size.
this is what it looks initially currently, though I want it to maintain this "ratio" while adjusting the page size.
current result when adjusting width of screen:
.html contents:


        const options = [
            { id: 1, text: 'Weapon Training: Deflection' },
            { id: 2, text: 'Weapon Training: Followthrough' },
            { id: 3, text: 'Weapon Training: Power' },
            { id: 4, text: 'Weapon Training: Precision' }
        ];

        const nodeModalList = document.getElementById('nodeModalList');

        options.forEach(option => {
            const li = document.createElement('li');
            li.textContent = option.text;
            nodeModalList.appendChild(li);
        });
        .node-modal {
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
            position: fixed;
            z-index: 100;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
            overflow: hidden;
        }
        .node-modal-content {
            background-image: url('https://i.postimg.cc/52zxKxtD/modal-window.png');
            background-position: center;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-size: contain;
            animation: fadeIn 0.3s;
            position: relative;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            scale: 60%;
        }
        .node-close:hover,
        .node-close:focus {
            color: black;
            text-decoration: none;
            cursor: pointer;
        }
        .node-modal-list {
            margin-top: 11%;
            margin-bottom: 7.05%;
            border: 2px;
            padding: 1px;
            row-gap: 7px;
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            width: 33%;
        }
        .node-modal-list li {
            display: flex;
            padding: 12px 8px;
            cursor: pointer;
            color: white;
            justify-content: flex-start;
            align-items: center;
            background-image: url(https://i.postimg.cc/yY2KRkH2/row-background.png);
            background-position: center;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-size: 100% 100%;
            flex-wrap: nowrap;
            flex-direction: row;
            text-shadow: 2px 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
            font-size: 3dvh;
            height: 50px;
        }
        .node-modal-content img {
            width: 6dvh; 
            height: 6dvh;
            box-shadow: 0px 4px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2); 
            border-radius: 50%; 
        }

        .node-modal-list img {
            margin-right: 10px;
            cursor: pointer;
        }
    <div id="nodeModal" class="node-modal">
        <div class="node-modal-content">
            <ul id="nodeModalList" class="node-modal-list"></ul>
        </div>
    </div>




Background images don't scale the same way inline elements do. I'd suggest having the image determine the size the modal and overlay the menu. Then everything should scale with one another. - A bit like this - https://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/zYELEo

instead, use an img tag instead of background. that way your image will scale with the div and will be easier to align with other content on scaling the page up or down

Thank you @Paulie_D, I've applied the changes detailed and all is working as expected :).

As detailed in Paulie_D / Aniket Pandey's replies, adding an img element to the html in-place of using a background-image allowed the other elements to be positioned relative to the img edges.
https://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/zYELEo


* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-align: center;
}

.map {
  margin:10px;
  border:5px solid red;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;

}

.map img {
  max-width:100%;
  display: block;
}

.box {
  width:8%;
  height:8%;
  background-image:   url(http://www.clker.com/cliparts/W/0/g/a/W/E/map-pin-red.svg);
  background-position: top center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
  position: absolute;
}

#pin-1 {
  top:29%;
  left:36%;
}

.box:hover > .pin-text {
  display: block;
}

.pin-text {
  position: absolute;
  top:50%;
  transform:translateY(-50%);
  left:75%;
  white-space:nowrap;
  display: none;
}

.pin-text h3 {
    color:white;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000;
}
<div class="map">
  <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/68/Pleasant_View_housing_development%2C_Missoula%2C_Montana_-_panoramio.jpg/800px-Pleasant_View_housing_development%2C_Missoula%2C_Montana_-_panoramio.jpg" alt="" />
  <div id="pin-1" class="box">
    <div class="pin-text">
      <h3>My House</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>



